# Capturing response to a soapUI test run

Tags: web-services, soapui

I am using soapUI's testrunner.bat to to perform a test from the command line. I would like to examine the response to the web service call. This is easily accomplished from the UI, but I haven't seen an option that will dump the response to file.
Here is the command I am using:

> testrunner.bat -sSuite -cPingProduction -r -I "C:\Program Files\eviware\Projects\Project-webchecker-soapui-project.xml"

This command does generate a log file, but it has no response/requests in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this by creating a Test Step (within a Test Case) and using this Groovy Script:

```
def response = context.expand( '${request#Response}' ) 
// where request is the name of your request
new File( "C:/response.txt" ).write( response )
```

Your syntax for calling testrunner.bat is correct and I have verified that it works for me.